# Column descriptions in Polars

Tags: dataframe, python-polars

I have a Polars dataframe. I would like to add some column descriptions in the file of the dataframe, without changing the name of the columns. For pandas the following solution works pretty good. I have not found something equivalent which works with

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creating a DataFrame
data = {
    'Column1': np.random.rand(5),
    'Column2': np.random.rand(5),
    'Column3': np.random.rand(5)
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Column descriptions
column_desc = {
    'Column1': 'Description for Column 1',
    'Column2': 'Description for Column 2',
    'Column3': 'Description for Column 3'
}

# Add descriptions to DataFrame
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(col, column_desc.get(col)) for col in df.columns])

# Check DataFrame columns with descriptions
print(df.columns)
```

Comment: What file format are you serializing to? Don’t think there is something similar available for polars. I guess in the case of pandas you can’t serialize to a "standard file format" either, so it might be an option to write the description to a meta file keeping data and meta-data in widely readable file formats.

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5117 is the issue for this (column metadata)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with polars but you can do it with pyarrow. Here are a couple custom functions you can use

```
import polars as pl
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import numpy as np

def write_w_meta(df, where, meta):
    df_tab=df.to_arrow()
    df_tab=df_tab.replace_schema_metadata(meta)
    pq.write_table(df_tab, where)

def read_w_meta(where) -> (pl.DataFrame, dict):
    """returns a tuple where the first value is a polars DataFrame and the 
    second is an embedded column description that was created with write_w_meta"""
    df_tab = pq.read_table(where)
    meta = df_tab.schema.metadata
    meta = {x.decode('utf-8'):y.decode('utf-8') for x,y in meta.items()}
    return (pl.from_arrow(df_tab), meta)
```

With those you can now do:

```
column_desc = {
    'Column1': 'Description for Column 1',
    'Column2': 'Description for Column 2',
    'Column3': 'Description for Column 3'
}

# Creating a DataFrame
data = {
    'Column1': np.random.rand(5),
    'Column2': np.random.rand(5),
    'Column3': np.random.rand(5)
}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)


write_w_meta(df, "some_file.parquet", column_desc)

new_df, new_desc = read_w_meta("some_file.parquet")

print(new_df)
shape: (5, 3)
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ Column1  ┆ Column2  ┆ Column3  │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 0.782398 ┆ 0.496273 ┆ 0.531805 │
│ 0.025615 ┆ 0.106782 ┆ 0.157827 │
│ 0.69775  ┆ 0.75612  ┆ 0.20301  │
│ 0.004942 ┆ 0.112314 ┆ 0.005737 │
│ 0.253238 ┆ 0.111861 ┆ 0.056216 │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘

print(new_desc)
{'Column1': 'Description for Column 1',
 'Column2': 'Description for Column 2',
 'Column3': 'Description for Column 3'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something equivalent to the pandas code you posted could be

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

# Creating a DataFrame
data = {
    'Column1': np.random.rand(5),
    'Column2': np.random.rand(5),
    'Column3': np.random.rand(5)
}
df = pl.DataFrame(data)

# Column descriptions
column_desc = {
    'Column1': 'Description for Column 1',
    'Column2': 'Description for Column 2',
    'Column3': 'Description for Column 3'
}

col_descriptions = (
    pl.DataFrame({"column": df.columns})
    # Add descriptions to DataFrame
    .with_columns(pl.col("column").replace(column_desc).alias("description"))
)

# Check DataFrame columns with descriptions
print(col_descriptions)
```

```
┌─────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ column  ┆ description              │
│ ---     ┆ ---                      │
│ str     ┆ str                      │
╞═════════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ Column1 ┆ Description for Column 1 │
│ Column2 ┆ Description for Column 2 │
│ Column3 ┆ Description for Column 3 │
└─────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

It seems like you are creating a new MultiIndex object to view the column descriptions, so I have followed a similar approach and created a new DataFrame in polars. I hope I am understanding your question correctly.

FYI I've also avoided using `df.columns` as a variable name and renamed it to `col_descriptions`. This avoids conflict with the attribute `df.columns`

Edit: you could even add the types of each column for additional context

```py
cols, types = zip(*df.schema.items())

print(
    pl.DataFrame({"column": cols, "type": (str(t) for t in types)})
    .with_columns(pl.col("column").replace(column_desc).alias("description"))
)
```

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ column  ┆ type    ┆ description              │
│ ---     ┆ ---     ┆ ---                      │
│ str     ┆ str     ┆ str                      │
╞═════════╪═════════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ Column1 ┆ Float64 ┆ Description for Column 1 │
│ Column2 ┆ Float64 ┆ Description for Column 2 │
│ Column3 ┆ Float64 ┆ Description for Column 3 │
└─────────┴─────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind answer. Unfortunately, I do not see how the two solutions are the same because in the case of the pandas, creating a multi-index allows me to add the information of the column description to the original data frame so that I can save that file and I will have both the data end the column description. 
With your solution I have the impression that I need to save two objects `col_descriptions` and `df`, which is not what I want. I would like to put either a MultiIndex or a sort of metadata to the columns so that I do not have an additional file to store.